# vector::operator[] overhead

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Apparently, after profiling my (scientific computation) C++ code, 25% (!) of the time is spent with calls to `vector::operator[]`.  True, my code spends all of its time reading and writing in `vector<float>`s (and a few `vector<int>`s too), but still, I'd like to know if there's supposed to be some significant overhead of `operator[]` compared to C-style arrays?

(I've seen another related question on SO, but regarding `[]` vs `at()` -- but apparently even `[]` is too slow for me?!)

Thanks,
Antony

(edit: just for info: using g++ -O3 version 4.5.2 on Ubuntu)

Comment: Hope you made sure to turn optimizations on :) Would be good to know compiler & OS too.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that this is related to any *overhead* of calling `[]`, it's probably purely down the *number* of times you are accessing the vectors. May be look to tune your algorithm to reduce the number of times you need to access?

Comment: What's your STL implementation? And what are you profiling with?  Typically operator[] will have practically no discernible overhead over C-array subscripting in an optimized build. The act of measuring could be inhibiting optimizations (depending how it's done) or you could be using an STL with agressive error checking (Microsoft's in some configurations/versions for example).

Comment: How big are the vectors? Sequential or random access?

Comment: Relatively small vectors (a few thousand elements at most, often only a few dozen), with mostly random access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::vector::operator[]` should be rather efficient, however the compiler must be paranoid and for every call made to a function it must assume that the vector could have been moved somewhere else in memory.

For example in this code

```
for (int i=0,n=v.size(); i<n; i++)
{
    total += v[i] + foo();
}
```

if the code of `foo` isn't known in advance the compiler is forced to reload the address of vector start every time because the vector could have been reallocated as a consequence of code inside `foo()`.

If you know for sure that the vector is not going to be moved in memory or reallocated then you can factor out this lookup operation with something like

```
double *vptr = &v[0]; // Address of first element
for (int i=0,n=v.size(); i<n; i++)
{
    total += vptr[i] + foo();
}
```

with this approach one memory lookup operation can be saved (`vptr` is likely to end up in a register for the whole loop).

Also another reason for inefficiency may be cache trashing. To see if this is the problem an easy trick is to just over-allocate your vectors by some uneven number of elements.

The reason is that because of how caching works if you have many vectors with e.g. 4096 elements all of them will happen to have the same low-order bits in the address and you may end up losing a lot of speed because of cache line invalidations.
For example this loop on my PC

```
std::vector<double> v1(n), v2(n), v3(n), v4(n), v5(n);
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<1000; j++)
    {
        v1[j] = v2[j] + v3[j];
        v2[j] = v3[j] + v4[j];
        v3[j] = v4[j] + v5[j];
        v4[j] = v5[j] + v1[j];
        v5[j] = v1[j] + v2[j];
    }
```

executes in about 8.1 seconds if `n == 8191` and in 3.2 seconds if `n == 10000`. Note that the inner loop is always from 0 to 999, independently of the value of `n`; what is different is just the memory address.

Depending on the processor/architecture I've observed even 10x slowdowns because of cache trashing.

Answer (score 13):

In a modern compiler, in release mode, with optimisations enabled, there is **no** overhead in using `operator []` compared to raw pointers: the call is completely inlined and resolves to just a pointer access.

<del>I’m guessing that you are somehow copying the return value in the assignment and that *this* is causing the real 25% time spent in the instruction.</del>[Not relevant for `float` and `int`]

Or the rest of your code is simply blazingly fast.

Comment: This is of course assuming that you’re not using some esoteric standard library implementation with added runtime checks.

Comment: I think the OP mentioned something about `float` and `int`, doubt the copy could be the issue here(?)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there will be some overhead as typically a `vector` will contain a pointer to a dynamically allocated array where as an array is just "there". This means there will typically be an extra memory dereference in `vector::operator[]` over using `[]` on an array. (Note that if you have a *pointer* to an array this is typically no better than a `vector`.)

If you are performing multiple accesses through the same `vector` or pointer in the same section of code without causing the vector to perhaps need reallocating, then the cost of this extra dereference may be shared over the multiple accesses and may well be negligible.

E.g.

```
#include <vector>
extern std::vector<float> vf;
extern float af[];
extern float* pf;

float test1(long index)
{
        return vf[index];
}

float test2(long index)
{
        return af[index];
}

float test3(long index)
{
        return pf[index];
}
```

generates the following code for me on g++ (some guff trimmed):

```
.globl _Z5test1i
        .type   _Z5test1i, @function
_Z5test1i:
        movq    vf(%rip), %rax
        movss   (%rax,%rdi,4), %xmm0
        ret
        .size   _Z5test1i, .-_Z5test1i

.globl _Z5test2i
        .type   _Z5test2i, @function
_Z5test2i:
        movss   af(,%rdi,4), %xmm0
        ret
        .size   _Z5test2i, .-_Z5test2i

.globl _Z5test3i
        .type   _Z5test3i, @function
_Z5test3i:
        movq    pf(%rip), %rax
        movss   (%rax,%rdi,4), %xmm0
        ret
        .size   _Z5test3i, .-_Z5test3i
```

Note how the pointer and vector version produce *exactly* the same code, with only the array version "winning".

Answer (score 8):

In general, there should be no signficant difference.  Differences can
occur in practice, however, for various reasons, depending on how the
compiler optimizes a specific bit of code.  One significant possible
difference: you're profiling, which means that you're executing
instrumented code.  I don't know what profiler you're using, but it's
frequent for the compiler to turn off inlining for various reasons when
instrumenting for profiling.  Are you sure that this isn't the case
here, and that this is artificially causing the indexation to appear to
take a greater percent of time than if it were inlined.

Comment: +1 for the note about instrumented code. For fast code the only viable option is a passive statistical profiler (e.g. oprofile). Any form of instrumentation will make the measure pointless.

Comment: I compiled with option -pg and used gprof.  Perhaps that's the issue indeed.

Answer (score 1):

A pure array access is an (almost) direct memory read, whereas operator[] is a member method of vector<>.

If properly inlined, it should be the same, if not, the overhead is very significant for computation intensive work.